# How to write a list of combinations to a file in python

Tags: python

```
import itertools
stuff = [1,2,3]
for i in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        print(subset)
```

> Is there a way to write this to a file instead of printing it on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `open` a file and write your data , in it . but note that the `write` function only accept string so you need to convert your list to string with `str` function .

```
import itertools
stuff = [1,2,3]

with open('out.txt','w') as f :
   for i in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
      for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        f.write(str(subset))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import itertools
stuff = [1,2,3]
with open("a_file.txt", "w") as the_file:
    for i in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
            print(subset)
            the_file.write(str(subset))
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, you can `print` directly to a file, to do that you need a file object

```
out = open(filename)
```

and the keyword argument `file=` in your `print`

```
print(subset, file=out)
```

BTW, this is possible, albeit with different syntax, also in python 2

```
print >>out, subset
```